# i'm triying to install libgraph file in fedora but it getting error at makefile after ./configure

Tags: linux, makefile, fedora, graphics2d, configure

---

### ./configure make error

```
     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
     make[2]: *** [Makefile:377: libgraph.la] Error 1
     make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/vaishali/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.2'
     make[1]: *** [Makefile:552: all-recursive] Error 1
     make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vaishali/Downloads/libgraph-1.0.2'
     make: *** [Makefile:268: all] Error 2
```

**i getting these errors**

1. `make[2]: *** [Makefile:377: libgraph.la] Error 1`
2. `make[1]: *** [Makefile:552: all-recursive] Error 1`
3. `make: *** [Makefile:268: all] Error 2`

Comment: These are all _results_ of some other error, which you have not shown us.  A link command failed, which caused the error `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`, which meant that the make rule that invoked link command failed, which meant that the make rule that invoked the rule that invoked the link command failed, etc.  You need to look for the _FIRST_ error in the output, not the last error.  The first errors are the most important, and often the rest of the errors are just cascading issues from those.

Comment: `libgraph-1.0.2` is an ancient program, last update = year 2005. Will build OK with "build prerequisites" = `libguile*-dev, libsdl_image*-1.2*-dev`